# How to add an "edit" button and update database onclick?

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a table where it displays information but I want to add an edit button that for example says "Turned in" and update a column in a database when clicked.

I want to change "baatinn" from 0 to 1 when someone clicks the edit button.

[image: Database]

First of all, how do I add an edit button in the row and second of all what is the query to update "baatinn" to set the value from 0 to 1

HTML:

```
<tr>
   <th>Båt ut</th>
   <th>Båt inn</th>
   <th>Båtnr</th>
   <th>Fornavn</th>
   <th>Etternavn</th>
   <th>Tid</th>
   <th>Kr</th>
   <th>Edit</th>
</tr>
```

PHP:

```
$sql = "SELECT utleid, inntid, baatnr, fornavn, etternavn, tid, kr, baatin FROM utleie WHERE baatnr LIKE '%$sok%' or fornavn LIKE '%$sok%' or etternavn LIKE '%$sok%' or tid LIKE '%$sok%' ORDER BY id desc";

$result = $conn-> query($sql);

if ($result-> num_rows > 0) {
    while ($row = $result-> fetch_assoc()) {
        ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $row["utleid"]; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row["inntid"]; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row["baatnr"]; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row["fornavn"]; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row["etternavn"]; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row["tid"]; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row["kr"]; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row["edit"]; ?></td>
        </tr>
        <?php 
    }
    echo "</table>";
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
$conn-> close();
```

Answer (score 0):

You could change the Edit text to be:

```
<form method="post">
  <button name="edit" value="1">Edit</button>
</form>
```

Then in PHP add:

```
if ($_POST['edit']) {
   $con->query("UPDATE utleie SET baatinn=1");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As @Kristopher Ives stated you can use form to submit data through `POST` request back to the server, but if you're submitting multiple table rows as data you need to make sure that each row is stored separately to avoid overwriting of data. Your form could look something like this:

```
<form name="edit">
    <table>
        <?php

        if ($result-> num_rows > 0) {
            while ($row = $result-> fetch_assoc()) {
                ?>
                <tr >
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" name="utleid[]" value="<?php echo $row["utleid"]; ?>">
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <?php 
            }
            echo "</table>";
        } else {
            echo "0 results";
        }

        ?>
    </table>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```